# Jest errors without .babelrc React Native errors with it

Tags: react-native, jestjs

In a nutshell my existing React Native app works without a .bablerc, I can only get Jest working with a .babelrc (since I use es6 syntax), and once I add the .babelrc my react native app breaks with the following error.

[image: React Native Error Image]

After adding .babelrc I see several [BABEL] notes in my react-native server that aren't there without the .babelrc.  Here is one example (I removed path before node_modules) although I don't think this is a problem

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/node_modules/react-native-htmlview/vendor/htmlparser2.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
```

Is there a way to isolate the "react-native" .babelrc presets to only run with jest?  Is there an easier solution I'm missing to get both jest and react native to work side by side?  Are there additional presets in .babelrc I need for react native to be transpiled properly?

I'm on react native 0.29.0 and here is my .babelrc and package.json

.babelrc

```
 {
     "presets": ["react-native"] 
 }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "keymirror": "^0.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "ramda": "^0.21.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.29.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^0.6.1",
    "react-native-button": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-cookies": "git://github.com/sdg9/react-native-cookies",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-material-design": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-material-kit": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.30.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-shared-preferences": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-simple-store": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-actions": "^0.10.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.5.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^13.2.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^1.1.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.28.0",
    "jest-cli": "^13.2.3",
    "regenerator": "^0.8.46",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.9.5",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.3.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "haste": {
      "defaultPlatform": "ios",
      "platforms": [
        "ios",
        "android"
      ],
      "providesModuleNodeModules": [
        "react-native"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For RN, Jest runs your code through a slightly tweaked pre-processor that's specific to Jest (i.e. not quite the same thing that RN uses to build the app).  This preprocessor ships with RN in the `jestSupport/` directory, and you should specify it in your Jest configuration:

```
...
"scriptPreprocessor": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/preprocessor.js",
"setupEnvScriptFile": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/env.js",
"haste": {
....
```

I've just tested on RN 0.29 and Jest CLI 13.0.0, and my tests compile just fine with this configuration in my package.json, and a .babelrc that matches what you've put in the question.

Also, by the way, if you specify this preprocessor, you actually shouldn't need the .babelrc to run the tests.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I'm almost there but I use es6 import statements which jest is mocking even with jest.disableAutomock().  I confirmed if I switch to require() instead of import it works but I'm 1 import down 1843 to go and would rather find a way to keep my es6 import syntax. I can confirm jest with es6 import syntax works using .babelrc defining "react-native" preset but that sets me back to square one as it breaks my application.  Do you have any idea how to get es6 import to work with jest without using .babelrc?

Comment: It's because Jest essentially monkeypatches the `require` function (I find this annoying, to be honest).  Try putting `"automock": false,` as a key in your Jest configuration in your package.json.  For some reason turning off automocking globally in the config works with es6 imports, while `jest.disableAutomock()` calls in actual unit tests doesn't.

Comment: Thanks got it working with your help but in the end jest felt so finicky (and ran really slow) so I ended up switching gears and going with a [mocha approach](https://blog.formidable.com/unit-testing-react-native-with-mocha-and-enzyme-51518f13ba73#.erhyf3s2n)